# Why does chrome extension load an html template excluding it's head and body tags?

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I've ran into an extremely strange issue recently. My script(which is shown below) loads everything from an HTML template file just fine, except it *excludes head and body tags* and spits the entire content directly into `<html> </html>` tags. Here is the code which is run in the *content-script*:

```
// load new <html> and replace current <html> with it
$.get(chrome.extension.getURL('index.html'), function(data) {
    $('html').empty().append($.parseHTML(data));
});
```

I don't have the slightest clue about why is this happening. Any ideas about what might be causing this problem?

[image: Google chrome screenshot]

---

### Updates:

I've tried to load head and body *separately* and.. it worked! Here is the updated code:

```
// load new <head> and replace current <head> with it
$.get(chrome.extension.getURL('head.html'), function(data) {
    $('head').empty().append($.parseHTML(data));
});

// load new <body> and replace current <body> with it
$.get(chrome.extension.getURL('body.html'), function(data) {
    $('body').empty().append($.parseHTML(data));
});
```

It would be better if it didn't work. Now I am even more confused. What difference does the new code make? Does JQuery have problems parsing head and body tags?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope javascript gods will not get offended by what I'm going to say now. It seems like the problem with parsing `<head>` and `<body>` tags lurks down in the depths of JQuery code. I am not sure if it's a bug or not, but JQuery just ignores the mentioned tags along with the `<html>` tag also. *gasp*. Here is the code to illustrate this behavior:

```
console.log($.parseHTML('
  <html>
    <head>
      <link href="some.css">
    </head>
    <body>
      <p>nobody cares</p>
    </body>
  </html>
'));
```

The output of the above code is `[link, p]`